# Broadcast one channel in Numpy array into three channels

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a RGB image `img` which is of shape `(2560L, 1920L, 3L)` and another single channel image `mask` which is of shape `(2560L, 1920L)`. Now, I want to make this `mask` of shape `(2560L, 1920L, 3L)` i.e. I want to copy this single channel data into all the three channels.

I'm doing it as follows.

```
np.array([[[j,j,j] for j in i] for i in mask])
```

Is there a faster way of doing this using `numpy`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you absolutely want to have the mask being `(2560, 1920, 3)`, you can simply expand it along an axis (there are several ways to do that, but this one is quite straightforward):

```
>>> mask = np.random.random_integers(0, 255, (15, 12))
>>> mask_3d = mask[:, :, None] * np.ones(3, dtype=int)[None, None, :]
>>> mask.shape
(15L, 12L)
>>> mask_3d.shape
(15L, 12L, 3L)
```

However, in general, you can use these [broadcasts](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) directly. For instance, if you want to multiply your image by your mask:

```
>>> img = np.random.random_integers(0, 255, (15, 12, 3))
>>> img.shape
(15L, 12L, 3L)
>>> converted = img * mask[:, :, None]
>>> converted.shape
(15L, 12L, 3L)
```

So you never *have* to create the `(n, m, 3)` mask: broadcasting is done on the fly by manipulating the strides of the mask array, rather than creating a bigger, redundant one. Most of the numpy operations support this kind of broadcasting: binary operations (as above), but also [indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html):

```
>>> # Take the lower part of the image
>>> mask = np.tri(15, 12, dtype=bool)
>>> # Apply mask to first channel
>>> one_channel = img[:, :, 0][mask]
>>> one_channel.shape
(114L,)
>>> # Apply mask to all channels
>>> pixels = img[mask]
>>> pixels.shape
(114L, 3L)
>>> np.all(pixels[:, 0] == one_channel)
True
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped. The second snippet especially. :)

Answer (score 18):

```
np.repeat(mask.reshape(2560L, 1920L, 1L), 3, axis=2)
```

Comment: Simpler: `np.repeat(mask[..., np.newaxis], 3, axis=2)`.

Answer (score 7):

The dimensions can be expanded along the last axis and then tiled as follows.

```
mask = np.random.randn(200, 150)
mask3d = np.tile(mask[:, :, None], [1, 1, 3])
```

`[1, 1, 3]` tiles the mask 3 times in the last dimension.

Answer (score 2):

```
np.repeat(mask[..., np.newaxis], 3, axis=-1)
```